# How to understand large complicated module, "without" compiling and debugging it

Tags: c++, c, code-analysis

I have large module of multiple files, this module has no documentations, no proper comments and is really complicated ... it also has terrible variable names (like int x, char y ... etc)

I would have used debugger and break points to see the flow of the module, but I don't have the full system to be able to compile this module.

So I have to depend on the source code itself for now.

Any ideas please ?

Comment: Sometimes it helps to reverse engineer with a decent UML tool, to get a rough overview.

Comment: it's usually easier to understand a program using the code than using a debugger...

Comment: For the terrible variable names, you could try to deobfuscate them by seeing what they actually are and use a refactor tool to change their names.

Comment: Try to break it into smaller components and understand each one of them separately. Publish here the ones that you are unable to understand (but make sure that they are relatively small and compact, otherwise users will be reluctant to make an effort).

Comment: Yeah, I'd say just piece it together one by one in your head. As for tools, you could of course generate a call-graph. If it's really this monumental it might help to stub out some of the dependencies and then run it

Comment: Try to implement the same functionality yourself. Once you finish you will perfectly understand the original code :)

Comment: If you're talking up to some 10s of thousands of lines, I print in 2 columns of 80-characters, about 7pt fonts and close line spacing, and sit with some highlighters and pens until I've got it figured, preferably in a cafe.  Small print means you see a lot at once and can move back and forth between related code more easily.  Sounds weird, but works better for me than on-screen.  Alternatively, adding trace can help too, especially if you write logging that indents as it calls into functions and unindents as it returns....

Comment: Start from main and dry run it. If it is a well written code, you will learn a lot on your way.

Comment: It depends on how well-written and modular that stuff is. If you have clear interfaces sufficiently doxygen'd/commented, you can get away by figuring out what each module is doing (module can be a .lib file or a class, etc..). If that code is a huge amount of spaghetti code or with no modularity in mind you'll have a hard time even with a debugger

Comment: *"I have large module of multiple files, this module has no documentations, no proper comments and is really complicated ... it also has terrible variable names (like int x, char y ... etc)"* Welcome to the real world of software engineering :)

Comment: You are seeing the result of certain/(in my experience most) 'programmers' that seem to think that comments take too much time and are of no value.  Usually, the only commentary they have included is notes to themselves, which are totally cryptic to everyone else.  I am often hired to perform maintenance behind these 'programmers'!  The simplest way I have found to understand such a mess is to take individual files, often individual functions, perform a reverse engineering analysis on them, then add all the missing (or replace the misleading) commentary.

Comment: I usually windup refractoring the code to eliminate the duplicate variables and give meaningful (but not real long) names to all the variables, functions, etc.  And, on at least two occasions, the code was such a mess that it was actually quicker for me to start with a blank sheet of paper, using the messed code for hints on what the application is supposed to do, and proceed to re-write the application.

Comment: the doxygen tool, mentioned in an earlier comment, can be used for the auto generation of basic interface commentary.  You can then flesh out such commentary as you gain understanding of the underlying code.

Comment: If you re-compile all the code, with all warnings, etc enabled, you will probably find lots of unused variables, variables those names hide other variables of the same name, etc etc.  This kind of information can be very helpful in the process of understanding what the original programmer overlooked and what areas need immediate attention

Comment: the doxygen tool can be used to generate call diagrams, variable name lists and other structure and control flow diagrams.  Such information is very helpful in determing what some code is doing.  BTW: the last time I downloaded doxygen, it was free.

Comment: @Marian --> Thx for your answer, but how to implement the same functionality without knowing the modules functional requirements ?

Comment: @user3629249 --> Thx for your answer, can you please explain to me how to make such "reverse engineering" to a function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of the two basic approaches: bottom-up, or top-down.

- With bottom-up, you first try to find self contained functions. I. e. functions that don't call other functions in the module. They may call standard library functions or be recursive, but apart from that, they only interact with data. Try to grasp their meaning (and add corresponding comments, then move on to the functions that use the functions that you have already understood.

  The problem with this is, that it is hard to get the big picture with this approach.
- With top-down, you first try to identify the interface functions of the module. The functions that are supposed to be called from outside. Then you try to guess what they are meant to do, and try to derive, how they use the internal functions to achieve their goal. That allows you to derive what those internal functions are meant to do, and you can recurse down the call tree. This is quite similar to your debugger approach.

  The problem with this is, that it may be hard to identify which functions are interface functions. Many (most) libraries/modules don't bother to discern between interface and internal functions, the resulting .so file exports all the symbols. However, the developers may have collected all interface functions into one big header. If that is the case, you have a ready made complete list of interface functions from which you can start.

I usually try to combine both approaches, starting top-down, and then doing a depth first search for self contained functions that I can fully understand. This is the fastest way to combine the information about the purpose with the information about the inner workings.

---

Another very important tool for understanding code may be refactoring. When I have to read myself into a function that encompasses more than 50 lines of code, it is almost inevitable that after I've understood it, it won't be longer than 50 lines anymore.

In these cases, I try to identify relatively self contained section within the functions, try to understand, what they do, and factor them out into functions of their own. Another heuristic is to look for repetitive code, which can be factored out into one function that is called with different arguments. Once a function has been factored out, you know what it does, and you have a meaningful name for it, which makes the rest of the long function much more easy to understand. And you reduce the structural complexity of the long function with it.

When using this refactoring approach, it is very important to restrict yourself to doing only changes that you can prove that they don't change visible behavior: You have not fully understood the code, so if you make non-trivial changes, you can really mess it up.

Answer (score 3):

***Document*** it, and verify that against its actual behaviour.